# OKHTTP returns 401 error on POST request but it is working with POSTMAN

Tags: java, post, session-cookies, okhttp, http-status-code-401

I am using OKHTTP3 to make a POST request to my server code. It returns 401 UNAUTHORIZED error. However, the same thing works on POSTMAN. The only difference between POSTMAN and my code may be a session cookie (which I am passing as a header). Below is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import okhttp3.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main
{


  public static final String SESSION_URL = "http://localhost:8080/security/rest/token/access/session/0";
  public static final String CREATE_PROJECT_URL = "http://localhost:8080/managers/CDQRuntime/smartdq/training/";
  public static String PROJECT_NAME = "testproject201234";
  static String MANAGEMENT_TOKEN="YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=";
  public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
  {
    //Get session api call
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(SESSION_URL)
            .get()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + MANAGEMENT_TOKEN)
            .build();
    OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String serverResponse = response.body().string();
    System.out.println(serverResponse);
    JSONObject responseMap = new JSONObject(serverResponse);
    System.out.println(responseMap);
    String accessToken=(String)responseMap.get("access_token");
    System.out.println(accessToken);




    //Create Project api call
    JSONObject createProjectCallBody = new JSONObject();
    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json");
    createProjectCallBody.put("projectState","Initial");
    createProjectCallBody.put("projectName", PROJECT_NAME);
    createProjectCallBody.put("projectDescription","this is a test");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, createProjectCallBody.toString());
        request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(CREATE_PROJECT_URL)
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+accessToken)
            .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json").
                addHeader("SESSION", responseMap.get("session").toString())
            .build();
        System.out.println(request.headers().toString());

    client=new OkHttpClient();

    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response);




  }

  private static Map<String, Object> getStringObjectMap(String content)
  {
    return new Gson().fromJson(
              content, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()
      );
  }

}
```

Below is the link to working postman response

[authoriation and other headers in POSTMAN request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k7gZ.png)
Here is the body in postman
[Body sent in the POSTMAN request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4UKs.png)

After the various Sys outs, below is the console log, which shows the code is failing on the second api call, the token extracted from first response is correct

```
{"access_token":"eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiZGlyIn0..LppdczJz8iUazAT1MXF7wg.vu6sPxXGhvWUjujS8u67zfYSF9zWWXibsk8iyiDag3kXT63Q_fMVusPyIJWabbS-Aa3OS_jcWMI8veKu2kIKC_fTGn2VjfU4Rs4Gt4L95PnJnmeH11AxJi2z9Lq_dw35hVWQBWJZjhucihvb7A5p0z7vroa-5boeXHUJPg1qcfL_9S8ab91hIy2aBry4h_QSqOXp1hD22pE7KcrRFnbc3JoDhnoL9iBZQXXiUXyw9Cvce8krIkeD7_aZCIF7NVz66xZ9WKly3-OQDvR94EG4rTwAPAo8z2Zc6ioQSSdQWvXhij5V97Pjk4UPjHBP1kJxhC2y-aPfMBjnWZ0lhXtb7CfSsDwVKUl7egczsaL4-CQ3a_u9ptpDoXwXvQCTLChRbGkxaV4Lmhm7jbwaHo00xHpUP2XlPnaj7wNtqWDxZwJOUk5GVy4qGlnqpMhyJ-0YONcBxSOIcxSSZGR95h_ceiMHF4f2XDmosv-iIBvl8NuX_VC_atlsJ1_6DRPCFDR-X-p3oKWaLgwtH1JGv5F-bo9SeM6EeV9AE5PEweabiN9UtI72zuQKtiCa-1p690yWqK7F-CmZTNij4EZV7knleHoDdQ3SZhNPFnuybkq-0v8JJM2bPlkfzmxhSLIOzY87BcynHIVBPcXFt5FvBvFvzSKd1nhYMynfzuOsrq90Q3f-6k9WKvHAYhpJKNAkhGNWs11jgHAUrPS85Yub3kLEHMICunOKtVgwTSsjmkpMfd6QskIpdc17WWzCXg7XiKeCzNFyDpP6KNzQ0mHqw59ou0XMVByLZwDAeZIe00ix3kqVyI3o9ZIz0hZT5gs3OHzHDLOlYzq0TUB9qI3iucotmLgrX_nHP_FoR1wSmhe0xDnVQxWMRJksiu82cwyIqXtcMREMkn5Wyl4R5njfbickT-cpZ5Ru4v9twF2KAKknjDArNg7vyFbZEK9_TUsaLJzzF6N8-XOvWoibavCbeFXxd7fMaxTkMVYukNk1nXJOJQs_qPBL7ipJ3aMRBLofOF25Nf2KtSTaKC5COjOY0DrKaZ-FgNgN45S1NA45Ii4y-7BS40f7nrwruBM7SkFEZ5U_YtWMevKqKXvB12oj8WLRHmMtPYseLGBNSAS-QSZMYqZK3x36vGeTbVRdxlQ8UsjN.H8gItdZ6gh4z4g82KIDMbQ","session":"64b9f9c9-e994-474f-8106-bdbe22845dfd","username":"admin"}
{"access_token":"eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiZGlyIn0..LppdczJz8iUazAT1MXF7wg.vu6sPxXGhvWUjujS8u67zfYSF9zWWXibsk8iyiDag3kXT63Q_fMVusPyIJWabbS-Aa3OS_jcWMI8veKu2kIKC_fTGn2VjfU4Rs4Gt4L95PnJnmeH11AxJi2z9Lq_dw35hVWQBWJZjhucihvb7A5p0z7vroa-5boeXHUJPg1qcfL_9S8ab91hIy2aBry4h_QSqOXp1hD22pE7KcrRFnbc3JoDhnoL9iBZQXXiUXyw9Cvce8krIkeD7_aZCIF7NVz66xZ9WKly3-OQDvR94EG4rTwAPAo8z2Zc6ioQSSdQWvXhij5V97Pjk4UPjHBP1kJxhC2y-aPfMBjnWZ0lhXtb7CfSsDwVKUl7egczsaL4-CQ3a_u9ptpDoXwXvQCTLChRbGkxaV4Lmhm7jbwaHo00xHpUP2XlPnaj7wNtqWDxZwJOUk5GVy4qGlnqpMhyJ-0YONcBxSOIcxSSZGR95h_ceiMHF4f2XDmosv-iIBvl8NuX_VC_atlsJ1_6DRPCFDR-X-p3oKWaLgwtH1JGv5F-bo9SeM6EeV9AE5PEweabiN9UtI72zuQKtiCa-1p690yWqK7F-CmZTNij4EZV7knleHoDdQ3SZhNPFnuybkq-0v8JJM2bPlkfzmxhSLIOzY87BcynHIVBPcXFt5FvBvFvzSKd1nhYMynfzuOsrq90Q3f-6k9WKvHAYhpJKNAkhGNWs11jgHAUrPS85Yub3kLEHMICunOKtVgwTSsjmkpMfd6QskIpdc17WWzCXg7XiKeCzNFyDpP6KNzQ0mHqw59ou0XMVByLZwDAeZIe00ix3kqVyI3o9ZIz0hZT5gs3OHzHDLOlYzq0TUB9qI3iucotmLgrX_nHP_FoR1wSmhe0xDnVQxWMRJksiu82cwyIqXtcMREMkn5Wyl4R5njfbickT-cpZ5Ru4v9twF2KAKknjDArNg7vyFbZEK9_TUsaLJzzF6N8-XOvWoibavCbeFXxd7fMaxTkMVYukNk1nXJOJQs_qPBL7ipJ3aMRBLofOF25Nf2KtSTaKC5COjOY0DrKaZ-FgNgN45S1NA45Ii4y-7BS40f7nrwruBM7SkFEZ5U_YtWMevKqKXvB12oj8WLRHmMtPYseLGBNSAS-QSZMYqZK3x36vGeTbVRdxlQ8UsjN.H8gItdZ6gh4z4g82KIDMbQ","session":"64b9f9c9-e994-474f-8106-bdbe22845dfd","username":"admin"}
eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiZGlyIn0..LppdczJz8iUazAT1MXF7wg.vu6sPxXGhvWUjujS8u67zfYSF9zWWXibsk8iyiDag3kXT63Q_fMVusPyIJWabbS-Aa3OS_jcWMI8veKu2kIKC_fTGn2VjfU4Rs4Gt4L95PnJnmeH11AxJi2z9Lq_dw35hVWQBWJZjhucihvb7A5p0z7vroa-5boeXHUJPg1qcfL_9S8ab91hIy2aBry4h_QSqOXp1hD22pE7KcrRFnbc3JoDhnoL9iBZQXXiUXyw9Cvce8krIkeD7_aZCIF7NVz66xZ9WKly3-OQDvR94EG4rTwAPAo8z2Zc6ioQSSdQWvXhij5V97Pjk4UPjHBP1kJxhC2y-aPfMBjnWZ0lhXtb7CfSsDwVKUl7egczsaL4-CQ3a_u9ptpDoXwXvQCTLChRbGkxaV4Lmhm7jbwaHo00xHpUP2XlPnaj7wNtqWDxZwJOUk5GVy4qGlnqpMhyJ-0YONcBxSOIcxSSZGR95h_ceiMHF4f2XDmosv-iIBvl8NuX_VC_atlsJ1_6DRPCFDR-X-p3oKWaLgwtH1JGv5F-bo9SeM6EeV9AE5PEweabiN9UtI72zuQKtiCa-1p690yWqK7F-CmZTNij4EZV7knleHoDdQ3SZhNPFnuybkq-0v8JJM2bPlkfzmxhSLIOzY87BcynHIVBPcXFt5FvBvFvzSKd1nhYMynfzuOsrq90Q3f-6k9WKvHAYhpJKNAkhGNWs11jgHAUrPS85Yub3kLEHMICunOKtVgwTSsjmkpMfd6QskIpdc17WWzCXg7XiKeCzNFyDpP6KNzQ0mHqw59ou0XMVByLZwDAeZIe00ix3kqVyI3o9ZIz0hZT5gs3OHzHDLOlYzq0TUB9qI3iucotmLgrX_nHP_FoR1wSmhe0xDnVQxWMRJksiu82cwyIqXtcMREMkn5Wyl4R5njfbickT-cpZ5Ru4v9twF2KAKknjDArNg7vyFbZEK9_TUsaLJzzF6N8-XOvWoibavCbeFXxd7fMaxTkMVYukNk1nXJOJQs_qPBL7ipJ3aMRBLofOF25Nf2KtSTaKC5COjOY0DrKaZ-FgNgN45S1NA45Ii4y-7BS40f7nrwruBM7SkFEZ5U_YtWMevKqKXvB12oj8WLRHmMtPYseLGBNSAS-QSZMYqZK3x36vGeTbVRdxlQ8UsjN.H8gItdZ6gh4z4g82KIDMbQ
Authorization: Bearer eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiZGlyIn0..LppdczJz8iUazAT1MXF7wg.vu6sPxXGhvWUjujS8u67zfYSF9zWWXibsk8iyiDag3kXT63Q_fMVusPyIJWabbS-Aa3OS_jcWMI8veKu2kIKC_fTGn2VjfU4Rs4Gt4L95PnJnmeH11AxJi2z9Lq_dw35hVWQBWJZjhucihvb7A5p0z7vroa-5boeXHUJPg1qcfL_9S8ab91hIy2aBry4h_QSqOXp1hD22pE7KcrRFnbc3JoDhnoL9iBZQXXiUXyw9Cvce8krIkeD7_aZCIF7NVz66xZ9WKly3-OQDvR94EG4rTwAPAo8z2Zc6ioQSSdQWvXhij5V97Pjk4UPjHBP1kJxhC2y-aPfMBjnWZ0lhXtb7CfSsDwVKUl7egczsaL4-CQ3a_u9ptpDoXwXvQCTLChRbGkxaV4Lmhm7jbwaHo00xHpUP2XlPnaj7wNtqWDxZwJOUk5GVy4qGlnqpMhyJ-0YONcBxSOIcxSSZGR95h_ceiMHF4f2XDmosv-iIBvl8NuX_VC_atlsJ1_6DRPCFDR-X-p3oKWaLgwtH1JGv5F-bo9SeM6EeV9AE5PEweabiN9UtI72zuQKtiCa-1p690yWqK7F-CmZTNij4EZV7knleHoDdQ3SZhNPFnuybkq-0v8JJM2bPlkfzmxhSLIOzY87BcynHIVBPcXFt5FvBvFvzSKd1nhYMynfzuOsrq90Q3f-6k9WKvHAYhpJKNAkhGNWs11jgHAUrPS85Yub3kLEHMICunOKtVgwTSsjmkpMfd6QskIpdc17WWzCXg7XiKeCzNFyDpP6KNzQ0mHqw59ou0XMVByLZwDAeZIe00ix3kqVyI3o9ZIz0hZT5gs3OHzHDLOlYzq0TUB9qI3iucotmLgrX_nHP_FoR1wSmhe0xDnVQxWMRJksiu82cwyIqXtcMREMkn5Wyl4R5njfbickT-cpZ5Ru4v9twF2KAKknjDArNg7vyFbZEK9_TUsaLJzzF6N8-XOvWoibavCbeFXxd7fMaxTkMVYukNk1nXJOJQs_qPBL7ipJ3aMRBLofOF25Nf2KtSTaKC5COjOY0DrKaZ-FgNgN45S1NA45Ii4y-7BS40f7nrwruBM7SkFEZ5U_YtWMevKqKXvB12oj8WLRHmMtPYseLGBNSAS-QSZMYqZK3x36vGeTbVRdxlQ8UsjN.H8gItdZ6gh4z4g82KIDMbQ
Content-Type: application/json
SESSION: 64b9f9c9-e994-474f-8106-bdbe22845dfd

Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=http://localhost:8080/managers/CDQRuntime/smartdq/training/}
```

Comment: Posting a stacktrace would be helpful. Do you know if it is failing on the token session call or the  project call?

Comment: @shinjw please see the edits, I have added the console log. Also am I doing the write thing by sending cookie as part of header or should I do something else ?

Comment: You will need to read into OKHttp’s docs to figure out how to use cookies. You’re passing in a header named SESSION instead